# Updating specific column containing formula of Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel sheet containing more that 3000 records and I want to update a value of particular column that has expression like `=N8*(1+Q8)`.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

string query = null;
connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourcefile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";");
connection.Open();
cmd.Connection = connection;

query = "Update [Data$] Set [" + Column1 + "] = '" + value1 + "' where ShortCust Like '%" + customername + "%' AND ShortProd Like '%" + productname + "%'";

cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close();
```

When I run this application to update getting error

> "Cannot update '(expression)'; field not updateable."

How can I update this Excel column?

Comment: I believe (If I am not wrong) Cells with formulas are read-only and can't be changed like this. You can either use OpenXML or Interop to achieve what you want.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: You are not wrong, cells with formulae are definitely read-only. I spent ages looking for a workaround in OLEDB to this and eventually had to give in and use Interop.